# Spring-boot 2.1.7 Error: Unable to instantiate factory class

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter" when i try to use a dependency (agile-sdk) compiled with "2.0.3" version in 2.1.7 spring boot project.

I tried changing the spring boot project version from 2.1.7 to 2.0.3 and everything works fine. Wondering whats the incompatibility between the dependency (agile-sdk) compiled with 2.0.3 and my target project with version 2.1.7.

Here is my build.gradle dependencies

```
buildscript {

    ext{
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("com.kenshoo:gradle-fpm:$gradlefpm")
    }   

}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: springfox_version
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: springfox_version
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version: apache_commons_compress_version
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: apache_commons_lang_version
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: commons_io_version
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-core', version: aws_version
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version:aws_version

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation "com.*.ps:agile-sdk:$agilesdkVersion"

    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    runtime group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: groovy_version

    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: assertj_version

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.13'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version: '3.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-core', version: '1.7.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.7.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent', version: '1.7.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '1.7.1'
}
```

```
2019-09-26T14:43:31.284|INFO |*|*.Application||Starting Application on M-C02TF1QFGTFM with PID 50965 (/** in /**)
2019-09-26T14:43:31.289|INFO |*|*.Application||No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-26T14:43:31.343|INFO |*|o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext||Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@112f364d: startup date [Thu Sep 26 14:43:31 CDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-09-26T14:43:31.831|ERROR|*|o.s.boot.SpringApplication||Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:163)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:101)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationImportFilters(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:266)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.filter(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:237)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:386)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:830)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:563)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        at *.Application.main(Application.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition] is not assignable to [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:158)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
2019-09-26T14:43:31.832|INFO |*|o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext||Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@112f364d: startup date [Thu Sep 26 14:43:31 CDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
```

> Task :bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

  > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed